# Debug.Print all application names

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to list all the open applications in debug.print?

I tried the below code which doesn't work.

```
Dim app As Application
For Each app In Windows.Applications
 Debug.Print app.Name
Next app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Dim strComputer As String
Dim objWMIService As Variant
Dim colItems As Variant
Dim objItem As Variant

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", , 48)

For Each objItem In colItems
     Debug.Print objItem.ProcessId & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.Caption & " " & objItem.CommandLine  & " " & objItem.ExecutablePath
Next
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, I can't execute the code due to line                       Debug.Pring objItem.ProcessId & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.Caption & " " & objItem.CommandLine  & " " & objItem.ExecutablePath

Comment: Sorry, typo, Debug.Pring should be Debug.Print  I have fixed the code above. Wasn't sure if you wanted all that.  You may just want Debug.Print objItem.Name